# Load balancing with Nginx: POST requests are not forwarded to the next upstream server when the current is down

Tags: nginx, post, load-balancer

I'm using Nginx as a load balancer between two webservers.

I noticed that, when one of the two webservers is down, GET requests are well forwarded to the second one, while POST are not:

Here is the message I got with **GET** request, it is forwarded to the second server, and end with a proper 200:

> "xx.xx.xx.xx" 502 na.mysite.net [...] "server-01:443,
>   server-**02**:443" [...] 502, **200**

Here is the message I got with **POST** request, it ends with a 502:

> "xx.xx.xx.xx" 502 na.mysite.net [...] "server-**01**:443" [...] **502**

The upstream servers are defined that way:

```
upstream my-site{
        keepalive 16;

        # Web backend servers
        server server-01:443 max_fails=0;
        server server-02:443 max_fails=0;
}
```

Before you ask, I don't use **max_fails** nor **fail_timeout** because some requests can take a very, very long time (minutes) so I don't want them to be considerate as failed.

I would like to have the same behavior for POST requests, but I can't find information regarding this on Google or Nginx's documentation.

Any help is welcomed, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, this is by design to prevent data corruption:

> **non_idempotent** 
>   normally, requests with a non-idempotent method (POST,
>   LOCK, PATCH) are not passed to the next server if a request has been
>   sent to an upstream server (1.9.13); enabling this option explicitly
>   allows retrying such requests;

Answer (score 0):

To make the nginx server forward the request to the next server you need to use `non_idempotent` option.

From [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) (proxy_next_upstream section):

```
non_idempotent

normally, requests with a non-idempotent method (POST, LOCK, PATCH) 
are not passed to the next server if a request has been sent to an 
upstream server (1.9.13); enabling this option explicitly allows 
retrying such requests;
```